# bash: programmatically assemble list

Tags: bash, list

I'm trying to write a shell script which is assembling a list that will later be passed to `sort -n`.  If I do:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\n" | sort -n
```

the output is sorted just as I expect.  What I can't figure out is how to assemble the list from inside the script itself.  Here is the current script which tries to sum up how much space is used in a directory, sorted by file extension:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter directory/path to analyze: "
read path

extList=` find $path -type f -print | awk ' BEGIN {FS="."}{ print $NF }' | grep -v '/' |  sort | uniq `

for ext in $extList; do
  byteList=`find $path -type f -name \*.$ext -printf '%s\n' `
  sum=0
  for b in $byteList; do
    sum=$(( $sum + $b ))
  done
  sum=$(( $sum/1024 ))
  list+=`printf " $sum KB   $ext\n"`
done
echo $list | sort -n
```

I've tried a lot of things for the list+= line, but I don't get a true list.  I wind up with everything appearing as a single line, unsorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're seeing:

```
echo "$(printf 'foo\n')$(printf 'bar\n')"
```

Expected:

```
foo
bar
```

Actual:

```
foobar
```

This is because trailing linefeeds are stripped in the contents of `$(..)` and `` `..` `` command substitution.

Instead, you can use `$'\n'` or a literal linefeed. Both of these will correctly append a linefeed:

```
list+="foo"$'\n'

list+="bar
"
```

---

Once you fix that, here's your next MCVE:

```
list="foo
bar"
echo $list
```

Expected:

```
foo
bar
```

Actual:

```
foo bar
```

This is due to the lack of quoting in `echo $list`. It should be `echo "$list"`.

---

However, none of this is the bash way of doing things. Instead of accumulating into a variable and then using the variable, just pipe the data. This is what you're doing:

```
list=""
for word in foo bar baz
do
  list+="$word"$'\n'
done
echo "$list" | sort -n
```

This is more canonical:

```
for word in foo bar baz
do
  echo "$word"
done | sort -n
```

Comment: he should be using arrays, and he should stop grepping the output from `find`.

Comment: The grep is there because not every file has an extension.  I'm not worried about the few files that don't have an extension because most of my users are from the MS Windows world of thinking.

Comment: What @Kusalananda means is that this answer just solves your immediate problem (which is very true), and does not get into the non-blocking fixes: 1. Making it `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`, 2. Cleaning up the syntax (backticks were deprecated 20 years ago), 3. Fixing a series of edge cases like how your script can fail if your directory name contains various metacharacters, 4. Reducing tool duplication like how `awk` can do everything `grep` does but you still invoke them both in a row (this whole script should really just be a single `find | awk`, see #1). Try CodeReview if interested.

Comment: All are valid points, but sometimes you need a solution quickly and no one is granting me time to be an expert in every command line solution available.  There is _always_ room for improvement.  Whether it is worth the time necessary or not is ultimately my prerogative.  Thanks for the insight, though.

Comment: This is generally my opinion as well, which is why the answer itself only covered your "appearing as a single line" problem

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `` `cmd` `` strips trailing newlines. Another is that `echo $list` doesn't quote `"$list"`, so newlines are printed as spaces.

There's no need to build a list variable to then sort it later, though. Instead, try sorting all of the loop's output.

```
for ext in $extList; do
  ...
  printf " %s KB   %s\n" "$sum" "$ext"
done | sort -n
```

I'd suggest not storing the extension list in a string either. You could use a function:

```
extList() {
    find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P\n' | awk -F. 'NF>1 {print $NF}' | sort -u
}

extList | while IFS= read -r ext; do
    ...
done | sort -n
```

Or store them in an array:

```
readarray -t extList < <(find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P\n' | awk -F. 'NF>1 {print $NF}' | sort -u)

for ext in "${extList[@]}"; do
    ...
done | sort -n
```